# Do ports need to be opened on Hyper-V server for Virtual Server to communicate over those ports?

Tags: hyper-v, port

I have had some issues with moving quickbooks to one of our virtual machines. Is it necessary for me to open the same ports required by that application on the physical server, which is hosting hyper-v?

Comment: I've never heard of nor seen that in any Hyper-V environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. We run QB in VMs on Hyper-V. Only problem I'm aware of is the MAC has to fixed. If it changes the licensing throws a fit and QB will stop working.